WPF - Change Forecolor of sub-MenuItem
I'm afraid WPF Templates baffle me. I was needing a control similar to Winforms' DropDownButton. I'm nearly there by using a MenuItem Control, but I can't figure how to change the forecolor of the sub-menu items. Here's my code and the result:
<Style x:Key="DropDownButton" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">                    
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="2" ContentSource="Icon" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="7,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="1" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="-1">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer"  CanContentScroll="true" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>                    
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#2000A2Ed"/>                            
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<!-- ... -->
<Menu d:Background="Transparent" ToolTip="Sort Gists">
    <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource DropDownButton}">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <imaging:CrispImage Moniker="{x:Static catalog:KnownMonikers.SortAscending}" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
        <MenuItem Header="Alphabetical" Command="{Binding SortGistsCMD}" CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:GistSortMethod.Alphabetical}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <imaging:CrispImage Moniker="{x:Static catalog:KnownMonikers.SortAscending}" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Starred" Command="{Binding SortGistsCMD}" CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:GistSortMethod.Starred}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <imaging:CrispImage Moniker="{x:Static catalog:KnownMonikers.Favorite}" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Private" Command="{Binding SortGistsCMD}" CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:GistSortMethod.Public}">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <imaging:CrispImage Moniker="{x:Static catalog:KnownMonikers.Key}" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>


Result:

How do I set the text color? Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}" resolves to white in VS DarkMode, but this displays as black. I know this is likely setting the 'button' text color rather than the dropdownitems.

I couldn't get the code to run since I don't know what assemblies/libraries its using. Looks like visual studio sdk. If you're able to run this your best way of trouble shooting right now is to look at the live visual tree while debugging and find out what fore color it's inheriting to make it the unintended color.

If you are going about this, this way then you will need override the default style for MenuItem, then apply it via x:Key MSDN MenuItem Style, you could use a button and context menu or a popup and use MSDN hierarchical data template.

Is it a Visual Studio extension? If so, it might be an issue of Visual Studio color theme.
